# How many column were created?

Tags: sas

I have following code

```
DATA  work."WC7I7AHE"n
         (keep = "DMMCU"n "DMITM"n "DMVEND"n "IBVEND"n "IBVEND_1110"n )
      ; 
   
   attrib "DMMCU"n length=$12 format=$12. label="Business Unit"
          "DMITM"n length=8 format=8. label="Item Number - Short"
          "DMVEND"n length=8 format=8. label="Supplier Number"
          "IBVEND"n length=8 format=8. label="Supplier Number"
          "IBVEND_1110"n length=8 format=8. label="Supplier Number"
          "IBITM"n length= 8
          "IBMCU"n length= $12
          ETLS_W2NX3KTY4 length= 8
          ;
```

In keep it says 5 column and attrib it stated 8 column. Which one I should consider? This table has 5 column or 8

Comment: Run the code and check?

Comment: Actually I can run thats main problem, we have to convert to sql code without testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 columns.

The `keep=` option here will control how many columns are in the output data set.

There may be more columns in the data while the step is running. E.g. it may read in a data set with 8 columns. Or some extra columns might have been created during the data step.

But when the output data is written, it will only have the columns specified in the `keep=` option. Any other columns will be dropped.